# How do I disable a column using icefaces? 

Tags: icefaces

I want to disable a column, I use this code:

`<ice-cc:selectBooleanColumn title="Installed" property="installed" disabled="true" ></ice-cc:selectBooleanColumn>`

...but the column is still able to change.

Please help :)

Comment: Since no one is able to help you and ICEFaces EE Composite Components when paid come with a support service, please direct your question to ICEFaces [support](http://www.icefaces.org/main/support/) or [forums](http://www.icefaces.org/JForum/forums/list.page).

Answer (score 1):

By "disabled" you mean it shouldn't appear? Try rendered="false" maybe if this is the case.

Comment: I don't want to appear the column, I just want that the column be disabled that mean I can not click below

Answer (score 0):

There is no disabled attribute in selectBooleanColumn component, as said in [API docs](http://composite-component-showcase.icefaces.org/ee-composite-showcase/docs/tld/ice-cc/selectBooleanColumn.html). I fear this cannot be done using ice-cc:editableTable.